# Exporting an Actively Updated Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I update a table that has rows being inserted every few seconds, do I get the snapshot at when I called MySQLdump or will it try to catch up to the rows being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a snapshot from the moment that the database locks the table.
If you run:
`mysqldump database`, it will dump one table at a time, and it will be based off the time it starts dumping that particular table, not the moment you started running the dump.